# ASP.NET Web API - Getting 404 when posting a Base64 string with HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, web

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Trying to post a Base64 encoded byte array, and getting a 404.

The thing is, when I try it with a normal value ("test"), it works.

API:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post(dynamic data)
{
  // ...
  return Ok();
}
```

Client:

```
public static bool UploadDocument(string base64Image)
{
  // ...
  using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true})
  using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
  {
    var data = new { Image = base64Image }; // Image = 123 (or any random value) Works.
    var res = client.PostAsJsonAsync(@"(url)", data).Result;
    if(res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      // ...
  }
}
```

Tried a couple other variations, also tried using WebRequest instead.
The issue remains.

Comment: Presumably youre expecting `PostAsJsonAsnc` to serialise the image to base 64. Is that definitely happening? What happens if you manually encode the image object as base 64, then attempt to post it?

Comment: @richzilla I'm already encoding it myself.

Comment: On closer inspection, yes you are...

Comment: Have you tried adding Content-Transfer-Encoding header. example httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TransferEncoding.Add(new TransferCodingHeaderValue("BASE64"));  
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/5_Content-Transfer-Encoding.html

Comment: Is it just that particular base 64 string thats causing problems? Can you base 64 encode the word 'test' and see if that goes through?

Comment: @richzilla Interesting, "test" does goes through

Comment: @Kaushal I think that only applies to emails.

Comment: 404 is HttpNotFound exception, is your endpoint false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the data I was trying to send was larger than the default maximum.

The 404 I got was actually 404.13, which is "Content Length Too Large".

You can find more about this [here](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits).